# Perform drag&drop in sandbox mac

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, draggable, sandbox, drag

How can I use NSURL or whatever to drag & drop files within my app?
There are many image conversion app tools that for example take a png file and create different size version by just drag & droping the file into it, I know how to do for old version target application but now with Sandbox don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW1

use NSPasteboard or NSApplicationDelegate as before sandbox. Add the appropriate entitlements to your compile target and your all set.